# Java basic console programming - can use hasNextLine to read inputs from console?

Tags: java, input, console

I have been presented with this code which looks unnatural to me. I would normally use `hasNextLine()` rather than a Boolean variable `done` as shown in this code in the `while` loop, but now I'm confused. My question is, can I replace the logic where the variable `done` is shown with `hasNextLine()` when input is expected from the console, or can I only use `hasNextLine()` when input comes from a file? Which is a better practice way of implementing this code where input comes from console, by using the `done` variable or `hasNextLine()`? Thanks.

```
// TCPClient.java

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class TCPClient{

    public static void main(String args[]){
    Socket clientSock=null;
    try{
        int port_num = Integer.valueOf(args[1]).intValue();  //get server's port no.
        clientSock = new Socket(args[0],(int)port_num);  // args[0] is the server host name

        /* String sock=clientSock.toString();
        System.out.println(sock); */

        PrintWriter oStream =
        new PrintWriter(clientSock.getOutputStream(),true);

        BufferedReader iStream =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                   (clientSock.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader keyInput =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        boolean done = false;
        String answer = iStream.readLine();
        if(answer != null)
        System.out.println(answer);

        while(!done){
        String line = keyInput.readLine();
        if(line.trim().equals("BYE"))
            done = true;
        oStream.println(line);
        answer = iStream.readLine();
        if(answer != null)
            System.out.println(answer);
        }

        clientSock.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your question has nothing to do with sockets.

Comment: While you are using sockets in your example program, the question is about console input (and the accepted answer too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in @Voo's solution because the `nextLine()` on `keyInput` could also return `null`.  Here's a corrected version:

```
String line;
while ((line = keyInput.readLine()) != null && 
       !line.trim().equals("BYE")) {
    oStream.println(line);
    answer = iStream.readLine();
    if (answer != null) {
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

---

> Can I replace the logic where the variable done is shown with `hasNextLine()` when input is expected from the console, or can I only use `hasNextLine()` when input comes from a file?

You can wrap any `InputStream` or any `Readable` (of which `Reader` is a subtype) in a `Scanner`, allowing you to use `hasNextLine()` on all of them.  The only caveat is that `hasNextLine()` can potentially block indefinitely waiting for input if the underlying stream comes from a console, pipe, socket or similar.

> Which is a better practice way of implementing this code where input comes from console, by using the `done` variable or `hasNextLine()`?

Either will do, as will the third option as illustrated above.  It is really a matter of taste ... and what you think looks simplest.  (Personally, I'd not use `Scanner` *just* so that I can call `hasNextLine()` ... but that's just my opinion.)

The other significant difference between using `Scanner` and `BufferedReader` is that `Scanner` hides any `IOException`s that might occur in a call to `hasNext...()` and returns simply `false`.  This is a good thing for typical use-cases of `Scanner` as a light-weight user input parser (as you are using it on `keyInput`), but maybe not in other use-cases.

Comment: Yep you're right, mea culpa. And just to note: We both changed the semantics of the program. The correct solution would be a do - while loop.

Answer (score 2):

Well your idea and the given solution implement different things. The given code stays in the loop until you get "BYE" from the input stream. Your solution would at first need a scanner or your own implementation of hasNextLine() anyhow, since BufferedReader doesn't have one afaik.

But if it's only about using a boolean variable or not, well the alternative would be:

```
    String line;
    while(!(line = keyInput.readLine()).trim().equals("BYE")){
    oStream.println(line);
    answer = iStream.readLine();
    if(answer != null)
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
```

I can understand people who don't like assignments in other statements, but I've written similar code with checking the variable for != NULL or EOF, because I found it better readable. I wouldn't make it much more complicated than what you've got right now though and I'd probably go with the boolean variable in that case.