# Java, File Reader, going into infinite loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I wrote a program to read a file. It reads the file correctly. I tested using print statements. But after reading the last line in the file, the program doesn't stop. It goes into an infinite loop. I am guessing that my `while` loop keeps reading blank characters as the next line. I don't know how to fix it.

If I put a `break` in the `else` part, it just reads the first line and breaks out of the `while` loop. I am not sure why.

Please help me out.

Here is the code :

```
public static void InterpretMessageFromFile() throws FileNotFoundException{
    File inputfile = new File("FilePath");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(inputfile);

try
    {
        while (reader.hasNextLine())
        {
            //if the type of order is add order to existing Order Book
            if (reader.hasNext("A")){

                reader.next();
                String retrieve_ts = reader.next();
                int ts = Integer.parseInt(retrieve_ts);
                //int ts = Integer.parseInt(retrieve_ts, 2); //for binary file
                String retrieve_id = reader.next();
                int id = Integer.parseInt(retrieve_id);
                //int id = Integer.parseInt(retrieve_id ,2); // for binary file
                String or_side = reader.next();
                String retrieve_share = reader.next();
                int share = Integer.parseInt(retrieve_share);
            //  int share = Integer.parseInt(retrieve_share, 2); //for binary file
                String retrieve_price = reader.next();
                int price = Integer.parseInt(retrieve_price);
                //int price = Integer.parseInt(retrieve_price, 2); //for binary file
                System.out.println("Add Order : Id is " + id );
                AddOrderToExistingBook.AddNewOrder(id, ts, or_side, share, price);
            }

            //if it is cancel order
            else if (reader.hasNext("X")){

                reader.next();
                String retrieve_ts = reader.next();
                int ts = Integer.parseInt(retrieve_ts);
                //int ts = Integer.parseInt(retrieve_ts, 2); //for binary file
                String retrieve_id = reader.next();
                int id = Integer.parseInt(retrieve_id);
                System.out.println("Cancel Order : Id is " + id + " time stamp is : " + ts );
                //int id = Integer.parseInt(retrieve_id, 2); //for binary file
                //String retrieve_share = reader.next();
            //  int share = Integer.parseInt(retrieve_share, 2); // need to add back later, removing it for testing purposes
                CancelOrder.CancelPartOfOrder(id, ts);
            }

            //if it is delete order
            else if (reader.hasNext("D")){

                reader.next();
                String retrieve_ts = reader.next();
                int ts = Integer.parseInt(retrieve_ts, 2);
                String retrieve_id = reader.next();
                int id = Integer.parseInt(retrieve_id, 2);

                DeleteOrder.DeleteOrderFromBook(id, ts);


            }
            else{
                 // unexpected token.  
                // basically log as info and ignore.
            }
        } 
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java basic console programming - can use hasNextLine to read inputs from console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048290/java-basic-console-programming-can-use-hasnextline-to-read-inputs-from-console)

Comment: It looks like you're never actually consuming the line if you're in the `else`. So `reader.hasNextLine()` is always true because you're not advancing.

Comment: Yes, I think thats the case. I tried fixing it putting a break statement in the else part. But it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you see when you step through your program in your debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When handling file reading operations, it is always good to check couple of conditions -
1) Does the file has next line? 2) Is the next line not null.

```
while (reader.hasNextLine() && (line = reader.nextLine()) != null)
```

And then you can use this `String line` in your code.

In you code, although you are getting the next value by `reader.next()`, It does not advance the pointer. That is the reason the loop never exits.

Ref: [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

The last else block does not actually consume the line. Therefore if you've got any characters after the last line of real data in your input the program will always have a next line. Try consuming the file one line at a time and then using `String.split()` to get the individual tokens in each line. This guarantees that you will consume every line in the file.